# Pandas style format not formatting columns as Percentages with decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

Morning All,

Looking to format two columns as percentages with two and one decimal places respectivly. I used styles:

```
df = {'Client': ['A','B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Pct1': [0, 0.777777777777777, 3, 0.555555555555555],
        'Pct2': [0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.4]
      }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
df.style.format({'Pct1': "{:.2%}"})
df.style.format({'Pct2': "{:.1%}"})
print(df)

  Client      Pct1      Pct2
0      A  0.000000  0.000000
1      B  0.777778  0.000000
2      C  3.000000  0.333333
3      D  0.555556  0.400000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df.style.format({'Pct1': "{:.2%}",'Pct2': "{:.1%}"})
```

Output:

```
    Client      Pct1    Pct2
0       A      0.00%    0.0%
1       B     77.78%    0.0%
2       C    300.00%    33.3%
3       D     55.56%    40.0%
```

You can also bypass `style` with:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [f"{a:.2%}" if x.name == 'Pct1' else 
                    (f"{a:.1%}" if x.name=='Pct2' else a) for a in x])
```

which returns **a dataframe** that looks exactly like the above:

```
  Client     Pct1   Pct2
0      A    0.00%   0.0%
1      B   77.78%   0.0%
2      C  300.00%  33.3%
3      D   55.56%  40.0%
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm still getting the same issue. Possibly a install issue of the jinja2?

Comment: make sure you get rid of the redundant (and wrong) `print(df)`.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that, it is an error. I willd elete my answer, so to avoid confusion

Comment: I removed all print statements, issue persists. Is there a way to do this without using styles?

Comment: Hey @Quang Hoang, same issue with the lambda....what is interesting is this works:

df = df.to_string(formatters={
    'Pct1': '{:,.2%}'.format,
    'Pct2': '{:,.1%}'.format
})

Could it be a setting in my Pycharm?

Comment: Very strange, I forced with this:

decimals1 = 2
decimals2 = 1
df['Pct1'] = df['Pct1'].apply(lambda x: round(x*100, decimals1)).astype(str) + '%'
df['Pct2'] = df['Pct2'].apply(lambda x: round(x*100, decimals2)).astype(str) + '%'

Thanks for the answer, I'm sure it works on 99.9% of PC's